# Generate view with X and Y from geometry type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, geospatial, sqlgeography

In [sql-server-2012](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) I want to generate view with all points from geometry type. How can I do this?
View example

```
GeomKey | X  | Y
--------+----+-----
 1      | X1 | Y1
 1      | x2 | Y2
 2      | x1 | Y1
```

Example in Oracle with sys.SDO

```
select c.ngeometrykey,  z.* 
from gis_map.mp_geometry c ,    
table(sdo_util.getvertices(c.geometry)) z
```

Comment: What type of Geometry are you storing? Multipoints or something else?

Comment: I am using Point, Polygone and LineString

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in a view but you can create a table-valued user defined function (a function that returns a table) to get what you want.

This example uses a table defined as

```
CREATE TABLE GeoTable (GeomKey int, vector GEOMETRY)
```

which stores different geometry types (in the example I linked below I used POINT, MULTIPOINT, LINESTRING and POLYGON).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetVertices()
RETURNS @ret TABLE (GeomKey INT, X INT, Y INT, PointNo INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @max INT
    SET @max = (SELECT MAX(vector.STNumPoints()) FROM GeoTable) 

    ;WITH Sequence(Number) AS
    (
        SELECT 1 AS Number
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Number + 1
        FROM Sequence
        WHERE Number < @max
    )
    INSERT INTO @ret 
    SELECT
        gt.GeomKey
        ,gt.vector.STPointN(nums.number).STX AS X
        ,gt.vector.STPointN(nums.number).STY AS Y
        ,nums.number AS PointNo
    FROM GeoTable gt, Sequence nums
    WHERE nums.number <= gt.vector.STNumPoints()
    RETURN
END;
```

See this [sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0814c/2) for a complete working example.